# Django test client response context None

Tags: django, ubuntu, django-testing

I have moved my Django app from my development machine (OS X, Python 2.6.5, Django 1.2.3) to a staging server (Ubuntu VM, Python 2.6.6, Django 1.2.3).

If I now run my test suite on the staging server, two tests fail when using the Django TestClient because response.context is None (but response.content is correct).

For example:

```
self.assertEquals(self.session.pk, response.context['db_session'].pk)
```

These test cases pass on the development machine.

Has anybody encountered similar problems?

Comment: So the above assertion throws an error claiming that response.context is None?  Can we see a stacktrace?

Comment: Here is another discussion of likely the same issue: [Django unit test response context is None](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136048/django-unit-test-response-context-is-none/36703491#36703491)

Comment: For me this error happened when I enabled memcache caching on my development instance. After changing the cache configuration back to the DummyCache the error did vanish.

Answer (score 11):

You need to add the test setup statement.

```
import django
django.test.utils.setup_test_environment()
```

Find more details by following my link:
http://jazstudios.blogspot.com/2011/01/django-testing-views.html

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation:

> Although * your code * [+] would work in the Python interactive interpreter, some of the test client's functionality, notably the template-related functionality, is only available while tests are running. The reason for this is that Django's test runner performs a bit of black magic in order to determine which template was loaded by a given view. This black magic (essentially a patching of Django's template system in memory) only happens during test running.

So if you run it in a test run, it should work.

You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947855/django-test-client-response-contains-empty-list-of-templates)