# Django unit test response context is None

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Why is response.context None in the following tests? I've checked response.content and it is ''. if I remove the  assertIsNotNone line I get a TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscribable

```
def test_log_view_with_no_entries(self):
    """
    If no logs are available, an appropriate message should be displayed.
    """
    response = self.client.get(reverse('swpgr:logs'))
    self.assertIsNotNone(response.context)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    self.assertContains(response, "No logs are available.")
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['log_list'], [])

def test_log_view_with_one_entry(self):
    """
    Logs should be displayed it table.
    """
    time = timezone.now()
    t = LogEntry.objects.create(event_date=time, command_type="Test", command_source="Test Case",
        username="user")
    response = self.client.get(reverse('swpgr:logs'))
    self.assertIsNotNone(response.context)
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(
        response.context['log_list'],
        ['<LogEntry: 1 Test user: user>']
    )`
```

Comment: For me this error happened when I enabled memcache caching on my development instance. After changing the cache configuration back to the DummyCache the error did vanish.

Answer (score 6):

### Quick workaround

There is another member dict of Context class (derived from SimpleTemplateResponse) which is called **context_data**. Using this instead of just **context** will give the expected context dict (django 1.9).
But be aware, it's defined to be deprecated since django 1.8. So use it at your own risk. Unfortunately I didn't research a proper alternative until now.

### Background

The existence of the **context** attribute of a response seems to be dependent on the type of template engine (templates) you are using.
If you go for another engine than the one coming with django (default) you likely find the dict at the **context_data** attribute

### References

- [Testing responses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/tools/#testing-responses)
- [context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse.context_data)

Comment: `context_data` itself is not deprecated. The deprecation was "context_data used to accept a Context". [2.1 no longer mentions any deprecation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse.context_data)

Comment: In fact, the [Django docs themselves recommend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/template-response/#django.template.response.SimpleTemplateResponse.context_data) using context_data for other template engines

Answer (score 4):

I was having this issue and to fix it did the following in the setUp function:

```
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
```

Answer (score 1):

In our case the problem was not in `setup_test_environment()` (since `pytest-django` does call it for us automatically) but, as [@tobltobs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/444100/tobltobs) mentioned in his/her comment, it was caching.

Swapping

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
        'LOCATION': 'test-cache',
    }
}
```

with

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
    }
}
```

solved all the problems for us.

Answer (score 0):

`setup_test_environment()` installs a template renderer which will allow us to examine some additional attributes on responses such as `response.context` that otherwise wouldn’t be available. Note that this method does not set up a test database, so the following will be run against the existing database and the output may differ slightly depending on what questions you already created. You might get unexpected results if your `TIME_ZONE` in `settings.py` isn’t correct. If you don’t remember setting it earlier, check it before continuing.

ref:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial05/#the-django-test-client