# Cache settings override does not work

Tags: django, unit-testing, caching, django-settings

This is my cache setting:

```
ENABLE_CACHING = True

if ENABLE_CACHING:
    CACHES = get_cache()
else:
    CACHES = {
        'default': {
            'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        }
    }
```

I tried to override this setting in two ways:

```
@override_settings(ENABLE_CACHING=False)

@override_settings(CACHES={'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache'}})
class IndexViewTests(TestCase):
    def test_index_view_with_a_future_question(self):
        """
        Questions with a pub_date in the future should not be displayed on
        the index page.
        """
        create_question('Future question', 1,
                        [Choice(choice_text='Dummy choice')])
        response = self.client.get(reverse('polls:index'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_questions'], [])
        self.assertEqual(response.context['total_questions'], 1)
        self.assertEqual(response.context['total_votes'], 0)
```

Both do not override the settings and I have to do it manually again. How can this be fixed?
This is a example failed test result caused by enabled caching:

```
ERROR: test_index_view_with_a_future_question (polls.tests.IndexViewTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/david/Projects/easypolls/polls/tests.py", line 375, in test_index_view_with_a_future_question
    self.assertQuerysetEqual(response.context['latest_questions'], [])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: The first way won't work because the file has already been executed and the properties aren't lazy, but the latter should work. Please post an example of how you're using the override together with the test code. I've gotten the exact same code working in the past.

Comment: I added the test code.

Comment: The `response.context` is None, [maybe this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136048/django-unit-test-response-context-is-none)? I've had this before but can't remember what fixed it.

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned in the first comment of the linked question this is because of caching. The error also does not occur if I disable caching manually.

Comment: Did you verify inside the test case/view that the `CACHES` setting is not what you expect? Try printing it out.

Comment: It is very weird. The CACHES setting seems to be overriden, but for some reason the context does not exist and multiple other problems occur.